# Convert date using joda time and ignore time

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting

Using the below code I'm attempting to convert a time: `"2014-10-31T23:59:59"` to just 
`"yyyy-MM-dd"` format, so in this case `"2014-10-31"`.

Here is the code :

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestConvert {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-10-31T23:59:59");
        System.out.println("formatted date is "+dt.toString());
    }

}
```

exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-10-31T23:59:59" is malformed at "T23:59:59"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
    at (TestConvert.java:11)
```

How to ignore the time and just create a date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a different formatter to parse the date in its original format:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime dt = parser.parseDateTime("2014-10-31T23:59:59");

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println("formatted date is " + formatter.print(dt));
}
```

Comment: you code is not behaving as expected ? the output is "formatted date is 2014-10-31T23:59:59.000Z" when I expect it to be "formatted date is 2014-10-31". Also var "formatter" is never used ?

Comment: @blue-sky copy-paste mistake - indeed, you are correct. You should call `formatter.print` - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-10-31T23:59:59");
System.out.println("formatted date is "+dt.toLocalDate());
```

Comment: To explain, a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) is a date-only value without time-of-day or time zone. If your goal is truly date-oriented, then use the LocalDate class as shown here. If you need time-of-day and/or time zone but want to focus on whole days, then use [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class and call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) to get the first moment of the day.